# How to select elements based on children

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I'm not an expert in PowerShell or XPath but I'm struggling a bit on how to solve this apparently simple problem. Say that i have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cars>
  <Car>
    <Name>Car1</Name>
    <Colors>
      <Color>
        <Name>Indian yellow</Name>
        <Effects>
          <Effect>Blur</Effect>
          <Effect>Shadow</Effect>
        </Effects>
      </Color>
      <Color>
        <Name>Fireapple red</Name>
        <Effects>
          <Effect>Shadow</Effect>
        </Effects>
      </Color>
    </Colors>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Name>Car2</Name>
    <Colors>
      <Color>
        <Name>Indian yellow</Name>
        <Effects>
          <Effect>Blur</Effect>
          <Effect>Shadow</Effect>
          <Effect>Saturated</Effect>
        </Effects>
      </Color>
      <Color>
        <Name>Chrome black</Name>
        <Effects>
          <Effect>Saturated</Effect>
        </Effects>
      </Color>
    </Colors>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <Name>Car3</Name>
    <Colors>
      <Color>
        <Name>Indian yellow</Name>
        <Effects>
          <Effect>Shadow</Effect>
          <Effect>Saturated</Effect>
        </Effects>
      </Color>
      <Color>
        <Name>Fireapple red</Name>
        <Effects>
          <Effect>Saturated</Effect>
        </Effects>
      </Color>
    </Colors>
  </Car>
</Cars>
```

How can I use Select-Xml to select e.g. the name of cars with the color effect "Saturated"? Note that I need a unique collection of cars, e.g. Car2 must not be selected twice even though both colors have the "Saturated" effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath `/Cars/Car[Colors/Color/Effects/Effect = 'Saturated']/Name` should do.

Comment: Hi Martin, I really like the simplicity of this. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/Car[Colors/Color/Effects/Effect = 'Saturated'
     and
       not(Name = preceding-sibling::Car[Colors/Color/Effects/Effect = 'Saturated']/Name)
      ]
```

Comment: I had to change your example slightly (adding "Colors" in front of "/Color") but it proved to be exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Comment: I just found out that you actually don't need to provide the not() condition so I have moved the solution. Hope it's allright, it's still a good approach.

Comment: @boomshanka, Your question says: "Note that I need a unique collection of cars, e.g. Car2 must not be selected twice" and this implies that the real XML document that you have might have `Car` elements with the same name. If this is the case, then this solution still produces the wanted result, and the accepted answer selects more than one `Car` element with the same name. Thanks for the edit -- very early in the morning I am usually half - asleep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to learn xpath myself so this may not be perfect, but you could try:

```
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content C:\test.xml)
$names = $xml.SelectNodes('/Cars/Car[Colors/Color/Effects/Effect="Saturated"]') | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Or to use `Select-XML` as you asked, use this instead:

```
$names = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '/Cars/Car[Colors/Color/Effects/Effect="Saturated"]/Name') | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty '#text'
```

It extracts the names as strings to `$names` variable.

Comment: Hi Graimer, thanks for providing the alternate example. I forgot about the call to SelectNodes.